# EFCore 3 GroupBy+ToDictionary raises client side GroupBy is not supported

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.0

The following `GroupBy` query cannot be translated and will raise an error: `client side GroupBy is not supported`

```
IEnumerable<int> ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var q = db.Comments.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Identifier))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Identifier);
var map = await q.ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Count());
```

How should the query be rearranged to be able to run on the dbms?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After any group by, there should be a Select statement which uses only the Group Key (and it's properties) and aggregates. This is similar to the limitation in `Sql` languages. As an optimization, the EF core team could possibly support calling `ToDictionary` with the same limitation, but they've not, so we need to do it manually:

```cs
IEnumerable<int> ids = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var q = db.Comments.Where(x => ids.Contains(x.Identifier))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Identifier)
    .Select(x => new { x.Key, Count = x.Count()});
var map = await q.ToDictionaryAsync(x => x.Key, x => x.Count);
```

This will be translated successfully.